# Cannot use models in the config folder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a plugin that generates a navbar using PHP. The folder is in project/config/menu.php

It looks like this:

```
<?php

return [

//HORIZONTAL MENU LAYOUT -  MENU

    'horizontal' => [
        [
            'title' => 'bar',
            'link'  => '/bar/all',
            'active' => 'bar*',
            'icon'  => 'fa fa-sign-in',

        ],
        [
            'title' => 'foo',
            'link'  => '/foo/all',
            'active' => 'foo*',
            'icon'  => 'fa fa-sign-out',
        ],
    ]
];
```

I want to add some model information.

This is my attempt:

```
<?php
use Auth;
$id = Auth::user()->id;

return [

//HORIZONTAL MENU LAYOUT -  MENU

    'horizontal' => [
        [
            'title' => 'bar',
            'link'  => '/bar/'. $id,
            'active' => 'bar*',
            'icon'  => 'fa fa-sign-in',

        ],
        [
            'title' => 'foo',
            'link'  => '/foo/all',
            'active' => 'foo*',
            'icon'  => 'fa fa-sign-out',
        ],
    ]
];
```

I get this error: `Class 'Auth' not found`. I have also tried with models:

```
$model = \App\Model::count();
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Call to a member function connection() on null
```

How do I use these models here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

laravel config loads before any other things, so instantiating model will give an error, and that error you are getting is due to no database connection information loaded during this specific config file loads. I wonder why you need to call model in config, you can simply build something like templates of menu layout like below:

```
<?php

return [

//HORIZONTAL MENU LAYOUT -  MENU

    horizontal' => [
        [
            'title' => 'bar',
            'link'  => '/bar/%d', // here %d is userId from database
            'active' => 'bar*',
            'icon'  => 'fa fa-sign-in',

        ],
        [
            'title' => 'foo',
            'link'  => '/foo/all',
            'active' => 'foo*',
            'icon'  => 'fa fa-sign-out',
        ],
    ]
];
```

and later replace that `%d` with value from model.